# SCART To HDMI recurrently loses signal: hardware problem, firmware bug, or else?

Tags: video-capture, digital-recording, hdmi, vhs

I just bought a [scart to hdmi adapter](https://www.amazon.fr/dp/B0BTYN8Z68?ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_product_details&th=1). It was not the cheapest as it also acts as a switch between 3 types of inputs : SCART, "3-cable AV", or just HDMI.

My goal is to video capture some VHS movies. Yet, even playing them on the TV fails with this adapter.

Here are the observations:

- Plugging the SCART-SCART cable directly between the VHS player and the TV works perfectly fine.
- Plugging the same SCART-SCART cable to the adapter and then plugging the HDMI to the TV results in the movie being "shredded": it oscillates between the actual movie and a "No Signal" blue screen
- The same problem happens if I plug the HDMI from the adapter to a computer:

  - on MacOS, using QuickTime
  - on MacOS, using VLC
  - on a PC with Debian Linux, using VLC

Conclusion is easy: the problem comes from the adapter/converter

Some people are just returning the product online, claiming it is faulty, but I'd like to go deeper.

**Personal Interpretation:**

this is not a hardware problem, but I have the feeling that the adapter is actually looking for another channel, as if there was a chance it could find a higher-resolution input. These devices are supposed to handle Game Console and many other things, so I assume it would make sense in those cases.

In the case I would be right, would there be a way to stick to the same channel throughout the movie?

Otherwise, what could be the issue?

Comment: Edit your post and add a link to the exact model of adaptor - you’re more likely to get a good answer

Comment: Done, thank you.